# How to annotate a type parameter in scala

Tags: scala, annotations, java-8

Java 8 supports annotations on type parameters such as

```java
class SomeBean {
     Optional<@Base64 String> bs;
}
```

How can this be written in Scala (if possible)?
I've tried the following (which compiles), but the resulting byte code does not make any mention of the `Base64` annotation:

```scala
case class SomeScalaBean(bs: Optional[String @Base64])
```

**Note**: if you're wondering, hibernate validator is making use of this, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#type-arguments-constraints

**Edit**: I created a ticket for this - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9883

Comment: If it's really just to restrict the input domain of a given type, why not just create a whole new type. Base64 Strings probably should not be left as simply the String type. You're asking for trouble. Wrap it in a class that makes sure it is Base64 when it is constructed. Scala "Value Classes" feature can help with this if you have concerns about the minimal overhead taken up by introducing a whole new class.

Comment: Bruno, have you compared both byte codes? I ask 'cause I have idea no Java annotations are represented at byte code.

Comment: @pedrofurla, the following byte code attributes hold the different kinds of Java annotations: `RuntimeVisibleAnnotations`, `RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations`, `RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations`, `RuntimeInvisibleTypeAnnotations`. The latter are used for Java 8 style TYPE_USE annotations.

Comment: @ScottShipp, yes that was my first intention but we have a lot of these value objects (email, civic number, zip code, etc...) which are all validated with annotations rather than with a wrapper. This is the javax validation approach.

Comment: @pedrofurla, I quickly went through the byte code with a simple `javap -v [...] | grep Base64` and the scala version does not return anything, whereas the java version does.